# Pass query string parameters to get data in updatedAt range

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I want to get data in a range of month/week/days it updated

```
this.userDetails = async (req) => {
    try {
        let updatedAt = req.query.updatedAt
        let start = moment().startOf('day')
        let end = moment().endOf('day')


        if (updatedAt) {
            usersByupdatedAt = await User.find({
                updatedAt: { $gte: start, $lte: end }
            })
        }
    } catch (error) {
        TE(error);
    }
};
```

and I search like this:

https://localhost:3000/users?updatedAt[gte]=2020-04-23T04:22:08.161Z&updatedAt[lte]=2020-05-23T04:22:08.161Z

and i get result as

```
{
    "usersByupdatedAt": [ ],
    "success": true
}
```

Comment: Try logging the query that you are passing to the find, to make sure it looks the way you intend.

Comment: Hi Amit, I don't see a question here, can you please clarify what you're inquiring about?  It may be helpful to add some sudo logic to clarify what you're expecting to occur. (ex. 1. get value of "updated[gte]" query parameter and use this as "start" value in mongo query 2. get value of "updated[lte]" query parameter and use this as "end" value in mongo query)

Comment: Hi @Aossey , i want to get data through postman as a string parameter.

e.g.- i want to query how many people and whom updated between April to May month or between date 2020-04-20 to 2020-04-26
  
and i don't know how to search in query string parameter.

Answer (score 0):

``

```
this.userDetails = async (req) => {
    try {
        const {updatedAfter, updatedBefore} = req.query;
        if (updatedAfter&&updatedBefore) {
            usersByupdatedAt = await User.find({
                updatedAt: { $gte: updatedAfter, $lte: updatedBefore }
            })
        }
    } catch (error) {
        TE(error);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

From the following tutorial https://masteringjs.io/tutorials/express/query-parameters

> If you use square brackets in a query string parameter, Express will parse that parameter as an object

The best way is just to `console.log(req.query)` to see how you can get certain query params.

It's advised to be careful with square brackets as the tutorial recommended (https://blog.websecurify.com/2014/08/hacking-nodejs-and-mongodb.html)

Nonetheless, your code can simply be fixed as follows

```
this.userDetails = async (req) => {
    try {
        let updatedAt = req.query.updatedAt
        // make sure updatedAt.gte & updatedAt.gte are valid dates
        let start = moment(updatedAt.gte).startOf('day')
        let end = moment(updatedAt.lte).endOf('day')


        if (updatedAt) {
            usersByupdatedAt = await User.find({
                updatedAt: { $gte: start, $lte: end }
            })
        }
    } catch (error) {
        TE(error);
    }
};
```